# How to improve performance of BesselJ to the level of GSL?

Tags: performance-tuning, numerics, special-functions

Consider the following code:

```
zs = N /@ Range[0, 12, 10^-5];
AbsoluteTiming[bessels = BesselJ[1, #] & /@ zs;]
Length @ zs
```

I've tried to measure only computation of `BesselJ[1, #] &` and filling of `bessels` with results. What I get is:

```
{12.103338, Null}
1200001
```

So OK, 12 seconds. Now I try the same with [GSL](http://www.gnu.org/software/gsl/) in C language and get this:

> 1200001 computations, time taken to compute: 0.223292 s

What's even stranger — at first I thought GSL just suffered from some accuracy problems, and thus was that fast. But when I actually compared the numbers, I found that it's *Mathematica* who gives worse precision, in particular for larger `z` (for small `z` the output is identical to GSL's). I used `N[#, 100] &` as reference values.

I assume there must still be some way to achieve performance in *Mathematica* that is similar to that of GSL; what is this way?

Comment: I deleted my answer since it doesn't actually *compute* the Bessel function. Nevertheless, the advice to use packed arrays and prefer listable functions still holds.

Comment: Btw, you do realize that (if the C program is your own) with your knowledge of C it is a simple task to create your own *LibraryFunction* that calls the GLS code? Check [this tutorial and all the references](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/CCompilerDriver/ref/CreateLibrary.html).

Comment: MATLAB's performance is on par with GSL.  There's no fundamental reason why Mathematica should be slow.  You could report this to WRI and ask them to improve performance.  Not only is MATLAB much faster, it is also much more precise, as verified with Mathematica's own arbitrary precision arithmetic (30 digits): http://i.stack.imgur.com/3nrOL.png

Comment: If need be, you can use the trapezoidal rule to evaluate a Bessel function of low integer order and small to moderately sized argument. That should be easy to do within a compiled function, if speed is of the essence. (For large arguments, use asymptotic expansions instead.)

Comment: @Szabolcs, I'd wager that this is because the built-in algorithm is a bit too general; that is, it's equipped to handle complex orders. For integer orders, the computations are not as complex, but it seems *Mathematica* does not know about them.

Comment: Hi, @halirutan, I found it really odd, All the special function will unpack packed array even used them Listably. I tried `Gamma`, `PolyLog`,...etc. Why? I thought mathematica claimed they did a lot of optimization for packed array. However, the whole bunch of special functions is not optimized?!!! I think this deserves a bug tag

Answer (score 33, accepted):

Following the advice in comments, I've made a test library for `BesselJ[1, #] &` function to evaluate via GSL. I still consider it a workaround, so if you find a way to use *Mathematica* built-in functions with good performance, please do make a new answer.

```
Needs["CCompilerDriver`"]
besselJ1src = "
  #include \"WolframLibrary.h\"
  DLLEXPORT mint WolframLibrary_getVersion() {return WolframLibraryVersion;}
  DLLEXPORT int WolframLibrary_initialize(WolframLibraryData libData) {return 0;}
  DLLEXPORT void WolframLibrary_uninitialize(WolframLibraryData libData) {}

  #include <gsl/gsl_sf_bessel.h>
  DLLEXPORT int j1(WolframLibraryData libData, mint argc, MArgument* args, MArgument result)
  {
    MArgument_setReal(result,gsl_sf_bessel_J1(MArgument_getReal(args[0])));
    return LIBRARY_NO_ERROR;
  }
  ";
besselJ1lib = CreateLibrary[besselJ1src, "besselj1", 
  "Libraries" -> {"gsl", "gslcblas"}];
j1 = LibraryFunctionLoad[besselJ1lib, "j1", {Real}, Real];
```

Now I can execute my original code with `j1` instead of `BesselJ[1, #] &`:

```
zs = N /@ Range[0, 12, 10^-5];
AbsoluteTiming[bessels = j1 /@ zs;]
```

> ```
> {0.241519, Null}
> ```

And `bessels` do indeed have numerical values.

Comment: +1, excellent self-answer! Nice use of the library function.

Comment: @Rusian: I am trying to resimulate your solution and need your help:  ... 
   "IncludeDirectories" -> 
    "C:\\dev\\vcpkg\\packages\\gsl_x64-windows\\include\\", 
   "LibraryDirectories" -> 
    "C:\\dev\\vcpkg\\packages\\gsl_x64-windows\\lib\\", 
   "Libraries" -> {"gsl", "gslcblas"}];
j1 = ,,,                                                                                                      
         Message: LibraryFunction::libload:The function j1 was not loaded from the file C:\Users\ld00032397\AppData\Roaming\Mathematica\SystemFiles\LibraryResources\Windows-x86-64\besselj1.dll.

Comment: @stocha my guess is that your system can't find `gsl` and `gslcblas` libraries. You may need to alter the system environment variable `PATH`, and maybe relaunch Mathematica after that.

Comment: Is "IncludeDirectories" ,"LibraryDirectories" not enough?

Comment: @stocha this is for compilation, while your problem is at the stage of loading the library after it has been compiled.

Answer (score 18):

I present in this answer a compiled implementation of one of the simpler algorithms for numerically evaluating a Bessel function of (modestly-sized) integer order and (small to medium-sized) real argument. This uses [Miller's algorithm](http://books.google.com/books?id=WGHWBoX89doC&pg=PA108):

```
bessj = With[{bjl = N[Log[1*^16]]},
             Compile[{{n, _Integer}, {x, _Real}},
                     Module[{h, hb, k, l, m, r, s},
                            If[x == 0., Return[If[n == 0, 1., 0.]]];
                            l = r = 1;
                            While[r = 2 l;
                                  r (Log[r] - Log[Abs[x/2]] - 1) + Log[6 r + 1]/2 < bjl,
                                  l = r];
                            While[r - l > 1, m = Quotient[l + r, 2];
                                  If[m (Log[m] - Log[Abs[x/2]] - 1) + Log[6 m + 1]/2 < bjl,
                                     l = m, r = m]];
                            h = 0.; s = 0.; hb = Internal`Bag[Most[{0.}]];
                            Do[h = x/(2 k - h x); Internal`StuffBag[hb, h];
                               s = h (s + 2 Mod[k + 1, 2]), {k, l, 1, -1}];
                            Internal`StuffBag[hb,
                                              If[n >= 0 || Mod[n, 2] == 0, 1, -1]/(1 + s)];
                            Times @@ Take[Internal`BagPart[hb, All], -Abs[n] - 1]],
                     RuntimeAttributes -> {Listable}]];
```

Compare:

```
zs = N[Range[0, 12, 1*^-5]];
AbsoluteTiming[BesselJ[1, #] & /@ zs;]
   {76.729389, Null}
AbsoluteTiming[bessj[1, #] & /@ zs;]
   {39.575264, Null}
```

However, the listability of both the built-in function and the compiled version are not being exploited here, so here's another test:

```
AbsoluteTiming[j1 = BesselJ[1, zs];]
   {74.120239, Null}
AbsoluteTiming[j1t = bessj[1, zs];]
   {24.816419, Null}
Max[Abs[j1t - j1]]
   2.94459*10^-13
```

Note that I did not do any compilation to C in this case; doing this ought to result in a function with even better performance.

Comment: Very useful answer! Indeed, using listability makes the biggest difference. Timings on my MacBook Pro are 14s for `BesselJ[1,zs]` and **3.8 s** for `bessj[1,zs]`. Using `Map`, the difference is much smaller: 14 seconds versus 11 seconds. `CompilationTarget -> "C"` gets me down to 2.3 s (with  `bessj[1,zs]`).

Answer (score 12):

> If need be, you can use the trapezoidal rule to evaluate a Bessel function of low integer order and small to moderately sized argument. That should be easy to do within a compiled function, if speed is of the essence.

I mentioned this in a comment months ago. Here is the long-overdue follow through. What follows is a simple routine for $J_1(x)$ for real, moderately sized $x$, using the midpoint rule (since, as it turns out, the expressions look simpler with it; the performance is similar, however):

```
bj1 = With[{bjl = N[Log[1*^16]], p2 = N[π/2]},
           Compile[{{x, _Real}},
                   Module[{m = 1, k, r, s},
                          If[x != 0., While[(8 m - 2) (Log[4 m - 1] -
                             Log[Abs[0.5 x]] - 1) + Log[25 m - 5] < 2 bjl, m++]];
                          s = 0.;
                          Do[r = Sin[(k + 0.5) p2/(m + 1)];
                             s += r Sin[r x],
                             {k, 0, m}];
                          s/(m + 1)],
                   RuntimeAttributes -> {Listable}]];
```

Admittedly, it does not have the generality of my previous answer, but it is concise and quite efficient:

```
AbsoluteTiming[j1 = BesselJ[1, zs];]
   {191.703, Null}

AbsoluteTiming[j1t = bj1[zs];]
   {37.6003, Null}

Max[Abs[j1t - j1]]
   4.44089*10^-16
```

For an explanation of why the trapezoidal/midpoint rule works so well, see [this](http://dx.doi.org/10.2307/2695765) or [this](http://dx.doi.org/10.1137/130932132).