# Mathematica's NIntegrate is so slower compare to scipy

Tags: numerical-integration, performance-tuning

In [this post](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/121046/4742), Antonov said Mathematica is better than scipy in integration.

However, I've tried several examples, Mathematica is always several times slower than scipy.

For example,

```
In[1]:= NIntegrate[x y + Sin[x^y], {x, 0, 4}, {y, 0, 4}, PrecisionGoal -> 8,
          AccuracyGoal -> 8] // AbsoluteTiming

Out[1]= {2.98762, 68.8117}

In[2]:= NIntegrate[x y + Sin[x^y], {x, 0, 4}, {y, 0, 4}] // AbsoluteTiming

Out[2]= {2.10989, 68.8117}
```

According to [this post](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/94671/4742), scipy's integration corresponds to `PrecisionGoal -> 8,AccuracyGoal -> 8`

Now look at scipy.

```
In [1]: import scipy.integrate

In [2]: import numpy as np

In [3]: %time scipy.integrate.dblquad(lambda x,y:x*y+np.sin(x**y), 0, 4,lambda x
   ...: :0,lambda x:4)
CPU times: user 593 ms, sys: 45.8 ms, total: 639 ms
Wall time: 638 ms
Out[3]: (68.8116996894142, 4.805091491642489e-07)
```

It is almost 5 times faster than 2.98762s.

What magic made scipy this fast? Any idea to make `NIntegration` faster?

---

What I actually want to is to plot integration result like this

```
Plot[NIntegrate[-2 Im[((-0.0006250000000000001` + ((3.5` + 
              0.02` I) + \[Omega] - 1.9` Cos[kx] - 
            2.1` Cos[ky]) ((3.5` + 0.02` I) + \[Omega] - 
            2.1` Cos[kx] - 1.9` Cos[ky])) ((-3.5` + 
           0.02` I) + \[Omega] + 2.1` Cos[kx] + 
         1.9` Cos[
           ky]))/(-0.0006250000000000001` (-0.0006250000000000001` + \
((-3.5` + 0.02` I) + \[Omega] + 2.1` Cos[kx] + 
             1.9` Cos[ky]) ((-3.5` + 0.02` I) + \[Omega] + 
             1.9` Cos[kx] + 2.1` Cos[ky])) + ((3.5` + 
            0.02` I) + \[Omega] - 1.9` Cos[kx] - 
          2.1` Cos[ky]) ((3.5` + 0.02` I) + \[Omega] - 2.1` Cos[kx] - 
          1.9` Cos[
            ky]) (-0.0006250000000000001` + ((-3.5` + 
               0.02` I) + \[Omega] + 2.1` Cos[kx] + 
             1.9` Cos[ky]) ((-3.5` + 0.02` I) + \[Omega] + 
             1.9` Cos[kx] + 
             2.1` Cos[
               ky])))], {kx, -\[Pi], \[Pi]}, {ky, -\[Pi], \[Pi]}], {\
\[Omega].-0.5, 0.5}]
```

each integration took more than 3 seconds, the plotting is slow. Do I really need to call scipy inside Mathematica. This way is awkward, and there is no standard conversion function to conveniently convert long expression to python form.

Comment: Did you call scipy from _MMA_? If so, could you post the full code?

Comment: @anderstood no, I run scipy in ipython

Comment: `NIntegrate[Integrate[x y+Sin[x^y],{y,0,4}], {x,0,4}, PrecisionGoal->8, AccuracyGoal->8]//AbsoluteTiming`

Answer (score 6):

There are various ways to fine tune `NIntegrate`. The difference of the following result to scipy's is of order `10^-7` and it needs less than a thenth of the computation time of `NIntegrate` without specified `Method`.

```
a = 68.811699689414;
{t, b} = NIntegrate[x y + Sin[x^y], {x, 0, 4}, {y, 0, 4}, 
   PrecisionGoal -> 8, AccuracyGoal -> 8,
   Method -> {"LocalAdaptive", 
     Method -> {"GaussKronrodRule", "Points" -> 9}}
   ] // AbsoluteTiming
a - b
```

> {0.176262, 68.81169993374982}
>
> -2.44336*10^-7

Comment: Thank you so much! Seems great. Your fine tuning also made my last complex integration 3 times faster. But this kind of find tuning requires so much knowledge... And I am curious, why `Automatic` option is so stupid, it has symbolicprocessing! Doesn't help to automatically decide a better method?

Comment: Well, `NIntegrate` is build as a swiss army knive that is able to _decide_ which tool to use. That requires some overhead. In this case, I know that the function is very oscillatory in a localized region, so `"LocalAdaptive"` might be a good idea. On the other hand, the function is very smooth (it is even analytic), so high order Gauss quadratures should help. The latter are less useful when there is a discontinuity or a pole in the integrant.

Comment: Without any a priori knowledge, Mathematica has to analyze the integrant and perform some checks to chose an integration strategy. This choice may be however suboptimal in certain cases...

Comment: @HenrikSchumacher Kudos for being polite and constructive in your answer and comments, given OP's attitude.

Comment: Thank you very much! "`NIntegrate· is build as a swiss army knive that is able to decide which tool to use". This enlighten me. I always thought `NIntegrate` as automatic tools in terms of Mathematica's powerful symbolic feature and thus give it too much expectation to operate automatically. I have to read more doc on integration : )

Comment: @AntonAntonov I am so sorry. I am absolutely not intend to be offensive. Sorry, sorry