# speed up evaluating a listable function

Tags: list-manipulation, compile, special-functions

I apologize in advance for the vagueness, but I can't think of a more descriptive title. I am trying to find the average value of the square of    `BesselJ[0, x]` evaluated over many lists. The function I am using is

```
f[h_, n_, m_] := Mean[BesselJ[0, h Table[Accumulate[Table[RandomChoice[{-1., 1.}], {j, n}]], {k, m}]]^2];
```

I am looking for ways to speed up this function for large values of `n` and `m`. Compiling doesn't help here since `BesselJ` is not compilable.

Comment: Have you seen [this](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/84982)?

Comment: @J.M. Thanks, that post is very helpful. However I could not reproduce what he did. I get an error saying it can not find the bessel header file...

Comment: I was obliquely referring to the answer I gave in that thread… I guess you never tried that?