# Radial Mathieu functions, divergence problem

Tags: calculus-and-analysis, evaluation, special-functions

I am working on a project that requires the utilization of even Mathieu functions.

This is the definition of my functions:

1. Even Mathieu function: `Ce[a, q, z] = MathieuC[a, q, z]`
2. Characteristic number of order m: `am[q] = MathieuCharacteristicA[m, q]`
3. Radial Mathiew function:

   ```
   Cem[q,x] = MathieuC[MathieuCharacteristicA[m, q], q, I x]
   ```

In my project, I have to work with the function `Cem[q, x]` with indexes `m = 2 r`, `r=1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, ..., 0 <= q <= 400`, and `0 < x < 20`.

So, this is the problem: The function `Cem[q, x]` explodes (becomes very badly behaved) when it is at the range `x > 2.5`, and get really worse for larger values of `q`. The next figure shows what I mean. Could anyone give me a suggestion on how to solve this problem? T

[image]

Comment: Please read the wiki info for the tag [tag:bugs]. Its use is reserved.

Comment: Try raising the `WorkingPrecision`: `Plot[MathieuC[MathieuCharacteristicA[4, 10], 10, I x], {x, 0, 4}, 
 WorkingPrecision -> 100]`  -- I think this question has been asked before.

Comment: Related: https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/124993/4999, https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/83032/4999

Comment: Thank you for your help. Nevertheless, I followed your posts, and I still have some issues. How can I do to evaluate the Mathieu functions (for instance, MathieuC[MathieuCharacteristicA[4, 10], 10, I x]) for arbitrary larger values of x (for instance x>3) and avoiding the problems mentioned in my original post? For instance, by doing Plot[MathieuC[MathieuCharacteristicA[4, 10], 10, I x], {x, 4, 10}, WorkingPrecision -> 100], it fails. Accordingly, I am afraid that I would also have numerical errors by doing numerical Integrations of such Mathieu functions in a range of {x,0,10}.

Comment: Basically, you're out of luck with Mathematica here. You may want to try [GLS's implementation of Mathieu functions](https://www.gnu.org/software/gsl/doc/html/specfunc.html#mathieu-functions), importing them into Mathematica as I did for Bessel functions [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/84995/5208).